# add div at start and end of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

Hi I'm trying to achieve this:

```
<div class="content">
    <img src= />
    <img src= />
    <div class="slideshow"> <img src= /><img src= /><img src= /></div>
    Some text here
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <i>Italic text</i>
    etc more text.
</div>

<div class="content">
    <img src= />
    <img src= />
    <div class="slideshow"> <img src= /><img src= /><img src= /></div>
    <div class="description"
        Some text here
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <i>Italic text</i>
        etc more text.
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried text nodes but it wraps all of the lines text in description divs. I'm trying to detect the first line of text until the last line of text. There will be no images, videos or slideshows after the description if that helps.

I must be missing something with the find node type=3

Any advice would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.project_content').each(function () {
  var tmp = [], collecting = false;

  $(this).contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length > 0) {
      collecting = true;
    }

    if (collecting) {
      tmp.push(this);
    }
  });

  $(tmp).wrapAll('<div class="description" />');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6EsRL/1/ this one wraps all elements from the first text-node to the next text-node.

http://jsfiddle.net/6EsRL/3/ this one wraps all elements from the first text-node to the last child-node.

Comment: Working very well @Yoshi but its not including <br> tags. Are they considered non-empty? Is there a way to include them in the div? http://jsfiddle.net/6EsRL/2/

Comment: @uriah Actually it's not the `br`, but at the moment it will only *search* until the next text node. If you want all nodes from the first text node I'll change to code to reflect that.

Comment: thats some wizardry right there. I'll try and work it how it works over the week. Thanks Yoshi

Comment: +1; Yich.  New to jQuery, and was trying to work out a solution to this problem.  Looks like you'll have to do custom filtering (like you're suggesting in this answer) because most jQuery tree traversal methods don't match text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

**Only if you can wrap the text nodes into a `<p>` or something**; You can use:

```
$('.content').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.slideshow').nextAll().appendTo( $('<div class="description"></div>').appendTo( $(this) ) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your content div doesn't have any other divs than slideshow inside of it, you can use this:

`$('.content').html(
                    $('.content').html().replace('</div>','</div><div class="description">')
                    +'</div>'
                );`

To wrap all content after slideshow div ending tag up to end of the content div into a description div.
[Demo](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9973028/WEB/slideshow.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Yoshi showed, you can use `.wrapAll()` if you find a way to select nodes after the `.slideshow` element.

Here's another way to do that.  I don't know how fast or slow it will be in comparison to Yoshi's solution, but it is simpler to understand:

```
var contents = $(".content").contents(); // Selects all nodes, including textual
var slideshowIndex = contents.index($(".slideshow"));
contents
  .slice(slideshowIndex + 1)
  .wrapAll('<div class="description" />');
```